# Stereographic projection continuous at $\infty$

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry

I have trouble with showing that the stereographic projection is continuous on $\infty$. I was given those two functions:

$$\pi:S^2\to\mathbb{C}\cup \{\infty\}$$

$$\pi(x_1,x_2,x_3) =\begin{cases}
\frac{x_1+ix_2}{1-x_3} & \text{if } (x_1,x_2,x_3) \neq (0,0,1) \\
   \infty       & \text{if } (x_1,x_2,x_3) = (0,0,1)
  \end{cases}$$

$$\psi : \mathbb{C}\cup \{\infty\}\to S^2$$

$$\psi(z=x_1+ix_2) =\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{1+x_1^2+x_2^2}(2x_1,2x_2,x_1^2+x_2^2-1) & \text{if } z \neq \infty \\
   (0,0,1)      & \text{if } z = \infty
  \end{cases}$$

And I was told to show that $\pi$ is an homeomorphism. To show that I need to show that $\pi$ is continuous, bijective and that its inverse is also continuous.

I see that the denominator of the two functions is never equal to zero, because for $\pi$ the only possible case would be (0,0,1) but this has another value and for $\psi$ is always greater than 1 and for this reason we can say that $\psi$ is continuous since composition of continuous functions. I've also shown that $\pi(\psi(z))$ = z and that $\psi(\pi(x_1,x_2,x_3))$ = $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ (This tells us that $\pi$ is the inverse function of $\psi$ and viceversa.)

My problem tells me to show that $\pi$ and $\psi$ are continuous in infinity, but I don't know how to show this. I wanted to use the limit criterion or the delta-epsilon criterion, but I'm not sure that I can use those for vectors (in case of $\pi$). Do you have any hint that would help me solving this problem?

I've also searched on the internet, but every source that I found said that this problem has an obvious solution, however for me it's not.

Comment: Technical quibble: As defined, $\pi$ is *not* a map $S^2\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ onto the complex plane. It is a map $S^2\rightarrow \mathbb{C}_{\infty}$ onto the Riemann sphere.

Comment: This of course depends on the topology of $\mathbb C$. In the standard euclidean topology, this is wrong. In the topology inherited from $S^2$ via this stereographic map continuity is trivial, after showing that the function is well-definined. (edit: of course only if $\mathbb C$ is compactified by adding the point at infinity, see MPW.)

Comment: Second  technical quibble: You are not showing this is a "homomorphism" as stated. You are showing it is a **homeomorphism**. The former is algebraic; the latter is topological.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An $\epsilon-\delta$ proof would be difficult since you don't have any definition of distance from infinity. So limits would be your best bet.

For a sequence $\mathbf x_n$ on the sphere converging to the north pole, show that $\liminf_{n \to \infty}|\pi(\mathbf x_n)| = \infty$.

Going the other way, if you have a sequence $\mathbf y_n \in \mathbb C\cup \infty$ so that $\liminf_{n \to \infty} |\mathbf y_n| = \infty$, then show that $\psi(\mathbf y_n)$ converges to the north pole.

For a sequence $\mathbf z_n \in \mathbb C$, saying that $\liminf_{n \to \infty} |z_n| = \infty$ means that for any positive real number, only finitely many of the $\mathbf z_n$ are within that distance from the origin. It is, in this setting, the most sensible way to define "converging to infinity".

Comment: Sorry, maybe a stupid question, but if $x_n$ is a sequence converging to the north pole, shouldn't it be $lim inf_{n \to \infty} | \pi (x_n) | = \infty$ instead of $|\psi (x_n)|$?

Comment: (Thank you for the hints However ;-) ) I think I could solve the problem of the convergence of a sequence $y_n$ to infinity $\implies$ $\lim inf \psi(y_n) \to (0,0,1)$ but I have a second maybe stupid question: if $x_n$ is a sequence converging to the north pole, then $x_n \to (0,0,1)$ right? How can I take the limit of $|\pi(x_n)|$? Should I consider every component by itself? How do the limit in more dimensional spaces exactly work?

Comment: @Ale I had indeed swapped the $\pi$ and $\psi$.
$$
$$
The $\liminf |-|$ thing is something you would do on a secuence in the complex plane, be it $\mathbf y_n$ or $\pi(\mathbf x_n)$. There is no reason to use it on a sequence of points on the unit sphere.
$$
$$
As for how you go about showing that it holds for $\pi(\mathbf x_n)$, first use the  $\epsilon$ definition of convergence on $\mathbf x_n$ and the north pole. Then transfer the $\epsilon$ neighbourhood of the north pole via $\pi$ to the complex plane, and see what it tells you about $\pi(\mathbf x_n)$

Comment: Ok, the definition that we had in class tells us that a sequence $x_n$ is convergent $\iff$ $\forall \epsilon \gt 0 \exists x_0 with x_n \in D_{\epsilon}(x_0) \forall x_n \ge x_0$ where $D_{\epsilon}(x_0)$ is the Ball of radius $\epsilon$ on $x_0$. Now my $x_0$ would be $N$ because we say that our sequence converges to the north pole.

So, if I evaluate $\pi( D_{\epsilon}(N))$ I get (is this true?) A neighbourhood on infinity that converges to infinity as $\epsilon \to 0$. The last passage seems strange to me because the neighborhood something like a donut on $\mathbb{C}$. Am I wrong?

Comment: ![$\pi(\D_{\epsilon}(N))$][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/8Sih8.jpg

Comment: @Ale You're very close. The neighbourhoods of $N$ (take for instance the northern hemisphere) gets mapped to everything _outside_ of some neighbourhood of the origin (in this case $\{z\in \Bbb C | |z| > 1\}$

Comment: Ah, ok. And this would mean that for ϵ going to 0 there does not exist any number on the complex plane which is in the neighborhood on the origin, right?

Answer (score 1):

I think there is something wrong in your problem. They're asking you to prove that the Alexandroff's compactification of $\mathbb{C}$ is $S^2$, right?

Well, for this you have indeed the stereographic projection and its inverse that are usual, continuous maps, whit no magic in them, if you just think about them as maps

$$
\pi : S^2 \setminus \left\{ (0,0,1)\right\} \longrightarrow \mathbb{C} \qquad \text{and}\qquad \psi: \mathbb{C} \longrightarrow S^2 \setminus \left\{ (0,0,1)\right\} \ .
$$

This way they're just plain continuous, with the usual topologies on both sides, bijective maps, inverse one to each other. Right?

Particularly, $\psi$ is an immersion into $S^2$ (continuous injective map such that $\mathbb{C} \cong \psi (\mathbb{C})\subset S^2 $ ) that leaves out of its range just *one* point (namely, $(0,0,1)$).

Ok, now use the following easy lemma.

**Lemma.** Let $X$ a locally compact and Hausdorff space and $\psi : X \longrightarrow Y$ an immersion into a compact Hausdorff space $Y$ such that $Y\setminus \psi (X)$ reduces to one point. Then $Y$ is the (homeomorphic to an) Alexandroff's compactification of $X$.

Comment: I think that lemma is basically the whole question here.

Comment: Essentially, what it says is that the Alexandroff compactification is unique. You can find a proof here http://www.ma1.upc.edu/docencia/assignatures/fme/topologia-fme/apunts/topo4.pdf , page 107, corollary 4.7.4. (See the previous proposition, though.) It's written in Catalan, but if you need a translation, I'm ready to provide it.

Comment: Oh, a downvote. Someone doesn't like basic topology, I see.   :-)

Comment: Anyway, if you're interested, here you can find what Wikipedia says about it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexandroff_compactification

Comment: I did not see immersion at school. What you have written can be right, but for now I can't understand it.

Comment: @Ale: and have you seen how to define continuity in $\mathbb{C} \cup \infty$?

Comment: @a.r. No, that's the problem. I don't really know how to prove the continuity in those cases. I was used to prove continuity of functions in $\mathbb{R}$, but in $\mathbb{C}$ and in $\mathbb{C} \cup \{ \infty \}$no. I don't really know hot to work in this case. Today I had a lot to do, but tomorrow I'll try to follow you hints.

Comment: @a.r. no, I downvoted, because I don't think the lemma you quoted is easy unless you already know enough to answer the question. If anything, I'd argue that your lemma is *more* difficult than the original problem to solve. I feel a bit bad because it's a nice, well presented answer. I just don't see how it helps.

Comment: @BenMillwood . Thanks for your explanation. Well, maybe all the apparatus of the Alexandroff compactification is too much for this problem, but without it I would like to see how you define a topology in this, apparently, weird thing $\mathbb{C} \cup \{ \infty\}$ and test continuity without some kind of "magic".